# Query related to Misclassification rate in Decision Trees

Tags: r, statistics, decision-tree

I am working on Decision Tree model .The dataset is related to cars.I have 80% data in training set and 20% test set. The summary of the model ( based on training data) shows misclassification rate around 0.02605 where as when I run the model on training set came as 0.0289 , the difference between them is around 0.003. Is the difference acceptable , what is causing this difference? I am new to R/statistics.Please share your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Acceptable misclassification rate is more art than science. If your data is generated from a single population then there is without a doubt to be some unavoidable overlap between the groups, which will make linear classification error-prone. This doesn't mean its a problem. For instance, if you are classifying credit card charges as possibly fraudulent or not, and your recourse isn't too harsh in the case when you classify an observation to the former, then you it may be advantageous to be on the safer side and end up with more false-positives rather than a low misclassification rate. You could 1. visualize your data to identify overlap, or 2. compute N*.03 to discern the number of misclassified cases; if you have an understanding of what you are classifying, you could assess the seriousness of misclassification that way.